# Simple multiples query AND

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new with Cypher and I can't handle with a simple problem. If someone can help I appreciate a lot.

I have this structure:

```
MATCH (p:person)-[k:KNOWS]->(pl:ProgrammingLangage)
```

So, for example, the simple query for those who knows java is:

```
MATCH (p:person)-[k:KNOWS]->(pl:ProgrammingLangage)
WHERE pl.name = "java" and k.years > 2
RETURN p.name as PERSON, k.years as YEARS, pl.name as PROGRAMMING_LANGAGE
```

I need to know the persons who knows *java* and *php* for at least 2 years both.

I tried `UNION`, tried `WHERE ALL`, `IN`, nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient or pretty, but this does the trick :

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[k:KNOWS]->(pl:ProgrammingLanguage)
WHERE  k.years > 2
WITH p.name AS PERSON, collect(pl.name) AS PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE
WHERE "Java" IN PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE
AND "PHP" IN PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE
RETURN PERSON, PROGRAMMING_LANGUAGE
```

If you need to group multiple languages you can't have the years in the result though (since that is specific to each language). Note that the result will also show any other languages that the person knows for more than two years (Java and PHP are mandatory).

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Dear Tom Geudens, thank you for your time and anwser. Indeed, it works. I didn't know about WITH tag not even collect... I'm going study more about it. Anyway, thank you for your reply. I appreciate!! I tryed to vote +1 but I don't have the repputation for it. Sorry =(

Comment: @lurinog Although you cannot upvote the answer, you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/360570) as the correct answer if it solve your problem. This is a good idea to show to other users that this question is solved.